# How is the number of distinct ordered bases be $ > p^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a vector space of $\text{dim } n$ over a ground field $\mathbb{F_p}$ (where $p$ is a prime). How is the number of ordered bases be $\displaystyle\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (p^n - p^k)$ when the total number of elements in the vector space is $p^n < \displaystyle\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (p^n - p^k)$. The fact that the total number of elements in the space is $p^n$ comes by choosing a particular basis $B = \{e_1,e_2, \cdots, e_n\}$ and writing out a $v \in V$ as $v = \sum \alpha_i e_i$ where each $\alpha_i$ can be chosen in as many as $p$ ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A basis of an $n$-dimensional vector space is a choice of a particular $n$-tuple of elements satisfying some condition. A basis lives in $V^n$. It would be surprising if the number of bases was larger than the cardinality of $V^n$, not that of $V$.

Comment: Are we talking of the space $V^n$ where $V$ is itself an $n-dim$ space? I think we are talking of $V$ and not $V^n$ (where again, $\text{dim } V = n$

Comment: @charlesh Yes, $V^n$ is the set of ordered $n$-tuples in $V$, where $V$ is itself $n$-dimensional. There is no mistake.

Comment: The statement that I read was : The number of distinct ordered bases for an $n$ dimensional vector space $V$ (over $\mathbb{F_p})$ is given by $(p^n - p^{n-1})(p^{n} - p^{n-2}) \cdots (p^n - 1)$. 

Do you mean that it should've been $V^n$ instead?

Comment: @charlesh No. Everything is correct. Just think about it calmly: you're comparing the number of bases to the number of elements in $V$. A basis is not an element of $V$.